# Async and Await Task - on which methods to make asynchronous in N-Tier application?

Tags: async-await

I'm new to using async and await. I have created an N-Tier console application which has a business logic layer and a repository layer. Some of the operations invoked by the user which makes a call to business and then to repository take a few minutes to execute before returning data to the user. I am confused about which methods to mark with the async Task and await. Should I make the methods in the Console app that make the call to the Business layer async while the application waits for the data to be returned after a few minutes? or should the methods in the business layer or repository be marked with async? Or shoud all methods in all layers be marked with async?

I basically want the application to work in the following way:

```
1) Application starts

2) Business layer called to retrieve data, the
application code moves on to make the next call to business layer, and
then the next business layer while allowing the other faster running
operations to return their data/text in the meantime, while the longer
running operations are still running.  

3) the longer running
applications complete at any point during the execution and output to
the console when they have completed eg not in any necessary order due
to the fact the methods are asynchronous.
```

How can I implement this? I know it is possible but I don't know which methods to put async and await in.

Comment: In general `async` should run all the way down to your IO. So every method after `static main` would be `async`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create yourself a `MainAsync` method and just await on it within the normal `Main` Method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var service = new ServiceA();
    var result = await service.GetValue().ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);

}

public class ServiceA
{
    private Repository _repository;

    public ServiceA()
    {
        _repository = new Repository();
    }

    public async Task<int> GetValue()
    {
        var v = await _repository.Get().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // business logic...

        return v * 3;
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    public Task<int> Get()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(10);
    }
}
```

Then async/await all the things!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to async and await 4 different methods, for example, so they are all running on different threads and therefore running in parallel at the same time?

Comment: Don't await them but store the task then `Task.WhenAll(task1, task 2,...) `

Comment: I tried your suggestion but after calling the line    `MainAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ` it doesn't continue to execute the next lines of code (while the long running operation in MainAsync is running, so it's the same as calling the long running method synchronously in terms of execution time. I might be doing something wrong!?

Comment: I don't understand, it runs the async methods in order and then it finishes when it finishes - just as it would do if they were being run without async/await and therefore takes the same amount of time?

Comment: It's easier to think about the `task` just being a handle to that given bit of work, `await`ing on it waits for it to complete/error/cancelled etc...

Comment: @Theomax: "async" does not mean "faster". It means "asynchronous" - i.e., not blocking the calling thread.

Comment: @KevinSmith: The `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `Main` is meaningless, since there is no `await` there.

Comment: @StephenCleary still gets the awaiter to get the result though... however there is no synchronization context set in this instance. I have a plugin that just forces me to write `ConfigureAwait(false)` due to all the library work I do.